# javascript get natural width/height of all images in table

Tags: javascript, html-table, image-size

I am trying to get the actual image sizes from the images listed in column **Image** and display it in column **Image Size**.

The problem I have is that I am only able to get the size of the first image, which is added in each cell for column **Image Size**.

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/a92ck0em/

```js
  var xmlFile = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joenbergen/files/master/XMLParse2.xml';

  function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", xmlFile, true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        xmlFunction(this.response);
      }
    };

  }

  function xmlFunction(xml) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    var table = "<tr><th>Category</th><th>Title</th><th>Image</th><th>Image Size</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ITEM");
    for (var elem of x) {
      var titles = elem.getElementsByTagName(
        "TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var cats = elem.getElementsByTagName("CATEGORY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var imageURL = elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE").length === 0 ? "..." : elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].getAttribute('url');
      var imageSize = elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE").length === 0 ? "..." : elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].width + 'x' + [0].height;

      table += "<tr><td>" + cats + "</td><td>" + titles + "</td><td>" + "<img src=" + imageURL + ' height="150" width="100">' + '</td><td id="cellId"><textTag>' + "" + "</textTag></td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = table;
  
    document.querySelector("img").addEventListener('load', function() {
      var imgTags = document.querySelectorAll('img'), i;
      for (i = 0; i < imgTags.length; ++i) {
          var image_width = document.querySelector("img").naturalWidth;
          var image_height = document.querySelector("img").naturalHeight;
      }
      $('#myTable textTag').each(function() {
      $(this).append(image_width + 'x' + image_height);
      //console.log(image_width + 'x' + image_height);
      });
    });
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Load</button>
<br><br>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

**Expected:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are many parts to your question, I started doing the simplest thing, logging that parsed xml document, looks like this:

```
...
<IMAGE url="...."></IMAGE>
<IMAGESIZE></IMAGESIZE>
...
```

So in your script you are getting an attribute that does not exist. So you can safely remove this line:

```
var imageSize = elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE").length === 0 ? "..." : elem.getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].width + 'x' + [0].height;
```

Next you need to check if the images are loaded, simplest thing to do:

```
"<img src=" + imageURL + ' height="150" width="100" onload="this._loaded = true;">' +
```

this will add a proprietary `_loaded` property to it.

Next you need to check when the images are loaded and once loaded fire a function, you need a recursive function to do that which does not blow the stack:

```
var imgTags = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    function isLoaded(){
        if(Array.prototype.slice.call(imgTags).some(function(d,i){return !d._loaded})){
        setTimeout(isLoaded,4);
      } else {
        $('#myTable textTag').each(function(i,node) {
         node.textContent = imgTags[i].naturalWidth + 'x' + imgTags[i].naturalHeight;
          //console.log(image_width + 'x' + image_height);
        });
      }
    };
    isLoaded();
```

I removed the `querySelectorAll(img)` bit, it is slower compared to `getElementsByTagName` and does not return a LIVE `HTML Collection`, returns a `NodeList`. The loaded function will fire your Jquery thing once it detects all the `_loaded` properties. The `Array.prototype.slice.call` is an old school way to convert `HTML Collection` or `NodeList` to a regular array, the cool kids you `Array.from` nowadays, it is up to you. You might also optimize the above function a bit by storing the result of `Array.prototype.slice.call...` once, I leave that to you. All in all it looks like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/h9evc81a/

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, that's a well detailed answer, I really appreciate it! And I can safely say that I would never have thought of adding onload to the img tag, I find that really clever. Marking this as answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to wait for the images to load before querying properties like `width` or `height`.

Normally this is done by setting an `onload` event handler that updates the display of these properties.

Moreover you're making a loop setting two variables and then, outside of the loop, you're assigning all the images the value of the very same variables.

You need to do the querying inside the second loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to click button twice it seems, most likely because the images aren't loaded yet as you say. I didn't notice this in jsfiddle when I tried it out at first. But do you know why only the first images dimensions are added to the cells? https://jsfiddle.net/a92ck0em/

Comment: @JoeBerg: I've added an explanation of why this happens... you're making a loop where you only set the variables, and then a second independent loop on the images. You need to make only one loop.